# unlocked package vs mdapi deploy

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx

Would I be correct in saying that unlocked packages should be used to deploy to partial and full orgs while mdapi:deploy should be used to deploy to developer orgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mdapi:deploy` is applicable for all the orgs. Whether it is a Partial, Sandbox, Production or DEV orgs .

Treat `mdapi:deploy` similar to the deploy options provided by Salesforce ANT migration toolkit; but instead of using those ANT tooling and Java jar, `mdapi:deploy` is baked into the Salesforce CLI.

Unlocked packages you can treat similar to an unmanaged packages prior but with upgrades possible (one of the biggest benefits). With unmanaged packages, upgrades were not possible; however with unlocked packages you get upgradability .

Note to generate unlocked package you need Salesforce CLI and command line unlike unmanaged packages where they could be generated in Salesforce org directly.